# I am having a Ruby Bundler error in my Rails project regarding Git file size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I even commented out the vendor file and yet it is still giving this error. Is there any way that it can be fixed? Otherwise it is saying that my git files are too large.

Here is the error:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1227/1227), done.
remote: error: Trace: 548f525c1d3f11afa76110ec518082916b2fe8d7d397eca70df6620d14166ad9
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0+0/cache/bundler/git/rails-fcf0202857b07db1a0f6220dae5ca99319ca0f32/objects/pack/pack-263ebbefd14ff7251d902b8eaee2d784646f38ee.pack is 188.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

I'd appreciate all help!

[image: The Rails git error.]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Why do you have the entirety of the Rails git repo in your git repo? Something's gone wrong here and the fix is to find out what, not increase limits on file sizes. Use a tool like `ncdu` to find out where the trouble is, you can quickly zero in on the problematic part of the repository.

Comment: You can "pin" Rails to whatever version you want, either a version number or a specific Git hash, all in your `Gemfile`. You don't need to `vendor/` it.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to figure out what your large files are. If you're ignoring the guidance from the error message and coming to SO with a question like this, I'd hazard a guess that you may have committed dependency directories like `node_modules` or `vendor` to version control (the error message also seems to be pretty clearly pointing to the large file as being in your vendor folder). You should add dependency directories to your .gitignore (e.g., `vendor/*`) and stage them for removal from git with:

```bash
git rm -r --cached directory_name
```

GH will warn you about files larger than 50 MiB and blocks files larger than 100 MiB. The error message git is giving you provides links to two resources, one of which is their [About Large Files on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github) documentation which will tell you everything you need to know about what's wrong and how to move forward. Please read the documentation.